# Issues reading events from RabbitMQ queue on Axon 3.3.5

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, axon

Using Axon 3.3.5, I am trying to read events from an AMQP queue.

```
/**
 * AMQP subscribing
 */

@Bean
SpringAMQPMessageSource notificationsEventsQueue(Serializer serializer) {
    return new SpringAMQPMessageSource(serializer) {

        @Override
        @Transactional
        @RabbitListener(id = "eventsQueue", queues = "notificationsEventsQueue")
        public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
            super.onMessage(message, channel);
        }

    };
}

@Autowired
public void configure(EventProcessingConfiguration conf, SpringAMQPMessageSource src) {
    conf.registerSubscribingEventProcessor("notificationsServiceEventProcessor", c -> src);
}
```

I debugged the `onMessage` method and when a new message comes in, the `eventProcessors` list is always empty, so the message isn't processed by my application.

What am I missing out?

Comment: Do you assign any of your event handlers to the notificationsServiceEventProcessor’ group?

Comment: Hi Allard, can you show how I should do that?

Comment: The easiest way is to put `@ProcessingGroup(“notificationsServiceEventProcessor”)` on your event handler class. Check out the ref guide for more info (docs.axonframework.org)

Comment: Thanks, Allard, that was right! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Handlers receive their events from the Event Bus by default. If you want handlers to receive events from another source (such as RabbitMQ), you need to explicitly assign that source to a processor, and assign that handler to that processor as well. 
The easiest way is to put `@ProcessingGroup('notificationsServiceEventProcessor')` on the eventhandler class.